Ckan PluginNotFoundException: scheming_datasets
I am trying to include ckan-next scheming extension, however when I run container on docker I receive an exception:
PluginNotFoundException: scheming_datasets

Installed the extension via the the Dockerfile.dev:

FROM ckan/ckan-dev:2.10.4
...
RUN  pip3 install -e "git+https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-scheming.git#egg=ckanext-scheming"
...
# Copy custom initialization scripts
COPY docker-entrypoint.d/* /docker-entrypoint.d/

# Apply any patches needed to CKAN core or any of the built extensions (not the
# runtime mounted ones)
COPY patches ${APP_DIR}/patches

RUN for d in $APP_DIR/patches/*; do \
        if [ -d $d ]; then \
            for f in `ls $d/*.patch | sort -g`; do \
                cd $SRC_DIR/`basename "$d"` && echo "$0: Applying patch $f to $SRC_DIR/`basename $d`"; patch -p1 < "$f" ; \
            done ; \
        fi ; \
    done


Added the extension to CKAN__PLUGINS in .env file:
CKAN__PLUGINS="envvars image_view text_view datatables_view datastore datapusher scheming_datasets"


probably your setup doesnt install the extensions correctly. You could try to attach to the CKAN container and try to install it manually the extensions you need .
Also you can check in the container environment with pip list to dpuble check if the extension got installed
